# Why doesn't C# compiler optimize unnecessary bit-wise operations?

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization

I realize the answer to this may very well be that it's just not interesting enough to optimize but this started when I was trying to give feedback to ReSharper about marking unnecessary bit-wise operations as just that.

I'm mostly curious as to whether there's a reason the compiler doesn't optimize something like this:

```
uint a = 0x33;
uint b = a & 0xffffffff;
```

where the '&' isn't doing anything (and irrespective of the value of a), but is retained in the release IL:

```
IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 51
IL_0002: ldc.i4.m1
IL_0003: and
```

Comment: C# compiler doesn't optimize a lot of things, but JIT compiler, which converts IL to native assembly code, has much more optimizations. It's very well possible that it is optimized at this point (by JIT), but to verify you need to view at generated assembly code.

Comment: If you mark them `const` then it will optimize it to just `ldc.i4.s 51`. Maybe there is some kind of hack that allows you to modify local variables at run time, with `ILGenerator` or something like that.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the optimize flag/compiling in Release? Anyway it was asked many times and answered by Eric Lippert. [What does the optimize switch do?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do/)

Comment: @Evk as a point of interest it appears the JIT Asm is similarly not optimized when the compiler is unable to predict the value of a.